# Pass data from one app to another app using Firebase

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, ios10

I am developing an app that has two parts - Rider & Driver, like Uber.  If the rider clicks on "request" and the driver "accepts" the request, I want to be able to have an alert pop up stating the driver has accepted your request.

Is there a way to pass data from one app to the other app and how would I attempt this?

I am also using Firebase as the database.

### Edit

Firebase database:

[image]

Comment: This question is way to vague to be answered accurately. Yes, there is a way, yes, Firebase can do that easily. Yes, there are 1000 other ways as well. Please review [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and update yours so we can help!

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your quick response.  Let me clarify.  I have a Rider app and a Driver App.  If the driver accepts the request, I want to have an alert pop in in the Rider app that the request has been accepted.  I thought passing the acceptedRequest = true from the Rider would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can be easily accomplished with Firebase. You would need a Rider node and a Driver node.

The rider would post a request to the driver's request node, which would notify the driver. If the driver accepts, that would be posted to the rider node who would be notified.

Each driver would add a Firebase observer to their driver node and each rider would add an observer to their rider node.

```
Drivers
  driver_01
    requests:
      rider_01: true
      rider_02: true

Riders
   rider_01
     responses
      driver_01: false
   rider _02
     responses
      driver_02: true
```

With the above structure, rider_01 has requested a ride from driver_01, and rider_02 has also requested a ride from driver_01.

driver_01 declined rider_01 request but accepted driver_02 request.

As the exchange occurs, riders and drivers receive events from Firebase which could then trigger a popup window.

Comment: I edited my post with my firebase database and how it is layed out

Comment: @LizG Good! My answer provides a similar layout and a solution for you to implement with Firebase using the observer pattern as shown in the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Working with Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). check out the Listen For Child Events section for details.

Comment: edited the firebase structure.  Still not able to trigger an alert but the database part is working fine.

Comment: @LizG If you are having some issues using Firebase observers and events to trigger alerts, ask another question so we can assist. Make sure to include your code as part of the question.